# How can I add a custom chrome extension to my Electron app?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, electron, add-on

I am facing some trouble adding chrome addons into my Electron BrowserWindow.

Before creating my window (and after the `ready` event has fired), I try to add a devtools extension that my browser needs to do screen sharing.

```
BrowserWindow.addDevToolsExtension('/home/USER/.config/chromium/Default/Extensions/dkjdkjlcilokfaigbckcipicchgoazeg/1.5_0');
```

I followed this [Electron guide](https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/devtools-extension), and it worked for their example (adding the react develop tool). When I do the exact same thing with my own chrome extension I have this error:

```
[4735:1116/163422.268391:ERROR:CONSOLE(7701)] "Skipping extension with invalid URL: chrome-extension://extension-name", source: chrome-devtools://devtools/bundled/shell.js (7701)
```

I don't really get why the error specified is "invalid URL" since I'm doing the exact same thing / process with the react addon without a problem. I also have no idea what to do. Is it possible that my chrome addon is not Electron-compatible?

Comment: Are you trying to add a standard extension (React devtools for instance) or one you’ve created yourself?

Comment: @MTCoster It is one our company created in order to enable screen sharing on our platform.

Comment: According to the documentation, it seems you have to specify different URLs for different operating systems. Which operating system is this being used/developed on?

Comment: @user3864563 We are developing / testing this on Ubuntu. Different URL must be specified for each operating system ? I could not find that in the documentation

Comment: @jineb92 It's not a different path, per se, but a different location where it would be located.

Comment: @user3864563 I just found some forums concerning Electron stating that Electron does not support Chrome extension. I fear that it might be impossible to do

Comment: @jineb92 It used to be the case that Electron did not support extensions. It does now.

Comment: Update, here's some more support: https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/extensions.md

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Support for Chromium extensions in Electron [is actively being worked on](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/19447) at the moment. The support isn't complete yet, but the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/19447) seems to have regular updates being posted.

Fingers crossed!

A current pull request is open for ['just enough extensions [api] to load a simple ... extension'](https://github.com/electron/electron/pull/19515)

Comment: i've tried to download and unpack some extensions from chrome web store to load as unpacked extension in electron but nothing worked. Hope Electron team will support this feature soon

Answer (score 8):

It looks like you're trying to add a regular Chrome extension instead of a Dev Tools extension.

The `BrowserWindow.addExtension(path)` method is for regular Chrome extensions:

> `BrowserWindow.addExtension(path)`
>
> - `path` String
>
> Adds **Chrome extension** located at `path`, and returns extension's name.
>
> The method will also not return if the extension's manifest is missing or incomplete.
>
> **Note:** This API cannot be called before the `ready` event of the `app` module is emitted.
>
> <sup>- https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#browserwindowaddextensionpath</sup>

Conversely, the `BrowserWindow.addDevToolsExtension(path)` method is for Dev Tools extensions:

> `BrowserWindow.addDevToolsExtension(path)`
>
> - `path` String
>
> Adds **DevTools extension** located at `path`, and returns extension's name.
>
> The extension will be remembered so you only need to call this API once, this API is not for programming use. If you try to add an extension that has already been loaded, this method will not return and instead log a warning to the console.
>
> The method will also not return if the extension's manifest is missing or incomplete.
>
> **Note:** This API cannot be called before the `ready` event of the `app` module is emitted.
>
> <sup>- https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#browserwindowadddevtoolsextensionpath</sup>

Note that in both cases you need to wait for the `ready` event from the `app` module to be emitted:

```js
const { BrowserWindow, app } = require('electron')

let mainWindow = null

function main() {
  BrowserWindow.addExtension('/path/to/extension')
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow()
  mainWindow.loadURL('https://google.com')
  mainWindow.on('close', event => {
    mainWindow = null
  })
}

app.on('ready', main)
```

Comment: I should indeed use .addExtension since I am trying to add a regular chrome extension but it is still not working. I'm still having the same error "Skipping extension with invalide URL: chrome-extension://extension-name". I'm adding the extension on click after the ready event so that could not be error

Comment: I have tried with other extensions such as grammarly and I have the exact same problem. [Here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/wimi-airtime-screen-shari/dkjdkjlcilokfaigbckcipicchgofemg?hl=fr&gl=FR) is the one I'm trying to import I think it might not be related to the extension but rather how I try to import it.
EDIT : I'm probably doing something wrong in the way I'm integrating the chrome-extension. Right now I'm taking it from the Extensions folder that is in .config/Chromium/Default/Extensions and paste it into my project. is it not how you're supposed to do it ?

Comment: Running into the same thing - has anyone found an answer?

Comment: same issue, any help?

Comment: It is deprecated as of May 1st 2021: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#browserwindowaddextensionpath-deprecated

Answer (score 6):

Electron 9 has much more support for extensions!

To load them, use `session.loadExtension`: https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/extensions.md

```js
const { app, BrowserWindow, session } = require('electron')

// ... in your createWindow function, which is called after app.whenReady

const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({...})

const ext = await session.defaultSession.loadExtension('/path/to/unpacked/chrome-ext')

console.log('ext', ext)
// outputs config file
// {
//   id: 'dcpdbjjnmhhlnlbibpeeiambicbbndim',
//   name: 'Up! – Free Social Bot',
//   path: '/Users/caffeinum/Development/GramUp/chrome-ext',
//   url: 'chrome-extension://dcpdbjjnmhhlnlbibpeeiambicbbndim/',
//   version: '1.7.0',
//   manifest: { ... }
// }
```

Read more: https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/extensions.md

Also, there's another project that helps you do that, also adds additional functionality: https://github.com/sentialx/electron-extensions

Answer (score 3):

While there is a documented [method to register a *normal* extension](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#browserwindowaddextensionpath), in majority of cases it won't do much, as Electron supports only an [accessibility subset](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/5842#issuecomment-223474257) of the `chrome.*` APIs (*apparently only the stuff required by [Spectron and Devtron](https://electronjs.org/blog/accessibility-tools)*) and as they've [stated a while ago](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/1498#issuecomment-96995155), they don't have any plans to support Chrome extension APIs at a full scale.